# Limiting the number of words or characters in the slug/permalink

Tags: permalinks, urls, slug

Limiting the number of words or characters in Wordpress slug/permalink. I would like to limit the number to the first 5 words (or 20 characters) even if the post title is longer.
example:
Title: Welcome to my site - this is my first post
url: mysite.com/welcome-to-my-site

Some function or alteration in the core Wordpress to achieve this result?

Comment: you can edit the permalink when adding a post, but there probably is a way to automate this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably do something with the `sanitize_title` hook based on the context conditionally, but I'm not familiar enough with where else `sanitize_title` is used to say for sure that this is a good solution. The trick to this is going to be limiting your slug without including stupid words that are going to hurt your SEO. As a launching point, try this:

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'wpse52690_limit_length', 1, 3 );

function wpse52690_limit_length( $title, $raw_title, $context ) {
    //  filters
    if( $context != 'save' )
        return $title;

    //  vars
    $desired_length = 20; //number of chars
    $desired_words = 5; //number of words
    $prohibited = array(
        'the'
        ,'in'
        ,'my'
        ,'etc'
        //put any more words you do not want to be in the slug in this array
    );

    //  do the actual work
    // filter out unwanted words
    $_title = explode( ' ', $title );
    //if you want more than one switch to preg_split()
    $_title = array_diff( $_title, $prohibited );
    // count letters and recombine
    $new_title = '';
    for( $i=0, $count=count($_title); $i<$count; $i++ ) {
        //check for number of words
        if( $i > $desired_words )
            break;
        //check for number of letters
        if( mb_strlen( $new_title.' '.$_title[$i] ) > $desired_length )
            break;

        if( $i != 0 )
            $new_title .= ' ';
        $new_title .= $_title[$i];
    }

    return $new_title;
}
```

Note that that is completely untested and I literally just wrote it, so it may have some kinks in it, but it's a good starting place for you.

Comment: You should use [`mb_strlen()`](http://wpengineer.com/2410/dont-use-strlen/) … and return something. A string would be useful. :)

Comment: @toscho You must have missed the last line, it returns `$new_title`. Thanks for the tip on `strlen()`, never knew that.

Comment: Ah, sorry. missed the scroll bar.

Comment: @m0r7if3r Gave error - Warning: Missing argument 2 for wpse52690_limit_length() in /functions.php on line 200

Comment: @MichaelWilliam The `add_filter` was missing the last argument, so WordPress didn't pass all three parameters to the callback. It is fixed now.

Comment: @toscho thanks for that fix, I always end up to make some dumb error when I don't test code lol

Comment: @toscho Ok, now gone. But not added trace in the first words and used only words 3 and not 5. Title: Welcome This is my first post - Slug: mysite.com/welcomethis-is/

Comment: @MichaelWilliam Fixed. I had `if( $i != 1 )` where I should have had `if( $i != 0 )`

Comment: @MichaelWilliam See m0r7if3r's answer (and every other answer on our site) as a hint for a possible direction. Do not expect – and do not ask for – complete working code without your own research efforts.

Comment: @toscho Sorry. I really am "abusing" their good will, lol. I'm actually enjoying that you're online. For you it is easier to change the code, because you created. And I'm just an enthusiast in php, and I am striving to learn more. Thanks for your great help.

Comment: @MichaelWilliam That's not my code, m0r7if3r has written it. :)

Comment: @toscho Slug is filtering of tags and categories too. Is there any way to make this code do not filter the slug of tags and categories?

Comment: There are, sorry. The question should be made ​​to @m0r7if3r, who created the function wpse52690_limit_length.

Comment: @MichaelWilliam Are you familiar with the concept of conditional application? Only add the filter where it's needed, and remove it immediately afterwards. That is all you're going to get out of me here, as there are already too many comments, and the issue is not with the code, but rather your implementation. I suggest you put in the research effort, and if you can't solve it, open a new question.

Comment: Ok, @m0r7if3r, I understand. I was trying if(taxonomy_exists('post_tag') || taxonomy_exists('category')), but is not working.

Comment: @MichaelWilliam Let me repeat myself. I am not going to support this question. It does not pertain to how the code works, it pertains to how you implemented my code, so if you need help with it, open another question, and someone else will help.